# Reading part number

Tags: watchdog

Can someone please guide me reading the part number? The screenshots are from a datasheet of a watchdog (STWD100).

I don't know how to relate these two..

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have the answer in the last page, device version

[image]

Comment: Hi @Radiohead I saw that, it helps me to understand the ordering code, but what I cannot relate are the Wathdog timeouts.. For example STWD100xY. Does this mean STWD?Y? (? being wild card)

Comment: That one in particular would be STWD100YxYxx3F, being the first "x" the output type and the "xx" the package

Comment: If that is the case then what does STWD100YxW mean?

Comment: The Y appears to be added as a new version.  The Device Version will be the 2nd or 3rd (automotive grade) character.  Timing's are shown.  For W \$t_{WD} = 6.3ms\$.

Comment: Hi @StainlessSteelRat, its really confusing to me, specially that added Y.. So the part number STWD100YNYWY3F has the Twd = 1.6S. Am I correct? Automotive Grade, Open Drain, 1.6S, SOT23-5

Comment: Looks good.  & -40 to 125 deg C.  Older version of [data sheet](http://pdf.eepw.com.cn/s20091116/755a087a369ea20b710a443124e5922e.pdf).  No automotive.